# some vim airline themes doesn't work

Tags: vim, vundle, vim-airline

I installed the [vim-airlines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tLOu.png) and its themes with `Vundle`. I changed my `.vimrc` to the following format:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
" call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
call vundle#begin('~/.vim/vundle_plugins')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" vim js plugin
Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript'

" auto complete
Plugin 'valloric/youcompleteme'

" file explorer
Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'

Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'

Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'

Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
" Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'

" 
call vundle#end()            " required

" nmap <F8> :TagbarToggle<CR>
let g:airline_theme= 'wombat'
if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
    let g:airline_symbols = {}
endif

" unicode symbols
let g:airline_left_sep = '»'
let g:airline_left_sep = '▶'
let g:airline_right_sep = '«'
let g:airline_right_sep = '◀'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '␊'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '␤'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '¶'
let g:airline_symbols.branch = '⎇'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'ρ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'Þ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = '∥'
let g:airline_symbols.whitespace = 'Ξ'
set laststatus=2
"set background=light

filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

but nothing happens. I mean the following picture:

[image: My terminal pic]

There is no theme change even after quitting the vim and reopening it. I installed both 'vim-airline' and `vim-airline-theme` today. So they are up to date.

Any comments is appreciated.

**Update**

- I'm using 64bit Linux Mint 17
- Vim version 7.4

Comment: What does the command `:AirlineTheme` print?

Comment: Also I'm confused why you have `Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'` commented out and using `Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'` instead.

Comment: @sudobangbang I just tried it out. Both libs give me the same result.

Comment: What is the result of `:AirlineTheme` ?

Comment: @sudobangbang it shows `wombat`.

Comment: @Hadi did you found an answer ? Same here on 64bit kubuntu 16.04 vim 7.4.

Comment: @elpddev No I didn't.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem.

Just add this line to your .bashrc/.zshrc file: `export TERM=xterm-256color`